# Apache2 Alias Prerequisites

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, alias, virtualhost

I have four Web development systems, two with Windows 10 and two with Ubuntu Linux and have set up Alias folders on three without a problem but am currently traveling and having trouble with the fourth. It is running Ubuntu with Apache2. A sample of one of the VirtualHost entries is below.

```
<VirtualHost devsite.dev:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/devsite.dev
    ServerName devsite.dev
    Alias /common/ /var/www/html/devsite.dev/common/
    <Directory "/var/www/html/devsite.dev">
        AllowOverride None
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Options FollowSymLinks
</VirtualHost>
```

The above does not work so what did I miss? All site folders including the common folder are in /var/www/html/ and I must have missed something as the alias is not working. In other words, each site has its own sitename.dev folder so http://devsite.dev/ pulls up the site but there is no physical folder within the site folder for http://devsite.dev/common/ to work so needs an Alias. Not sure if trailing slashes are needed or not and can't recall what my other systems have but either way it doesn't seem matter here.

When I say it doesn't work, I mean that the aliased folder does not show up in the PC's file manager as it does on all my other systems and the site cannot find it using the browser in order to load files from it as I showed above in the sample URLs.

Perhaps I was not too clear that common is not within /var/www/html/devsite.dev. Instead it is at /var/www/html/common and it does require an Alias to work. Also, there is already a DocumentRoot /var/www/html line in the Apache 000-default.conf file.

Comment: Why would you even need the ``Alias`` in this case? The directory already exists under ``DocumentRoot`` with the same name, and so would be found already as ``/common``. If it wasn't working, are you sure Apache is even using the ``VirtualHost``.

Comment: "common" is a folder that is shared by several sites and is in the server root but not in the individual Web site folder. The VirtualHost is working because the site works.

Comment: That isn't what your config says. You have ``DocumentRoot`` as ``/var/www/html/devsite.dev`` and the last argument to ``Alias`` is ``/var/www/html/devsite.dev/common/``, which is a sub directory of ``DocumentRoot`` and not in the server root.

Comment: That's that every reference I found shows and works on my other systems. The server DocumentRoot is /var/www/html/.  Are you saying that a VirtualHost does not need something to tell it where to find the files for the  site?

Comment: Is ``common`` actually a symlink? Even if it is and it links to ``../common`` or elsewhere, the ``Alias`` isn't needed. What would be needed though is a ``Directory`` directive for the ``common`` directory where it actually exists, granting access to it.

Comment: Instead of just saying it doesn't work, explain how it does not work. Did you get 403 Forbidden? What HTTP response code and message do you get in the browser? Indicate the actual path to your shared ``common`` directory.

Comment: And when I say explain how it doesn't work, I would anticipate you would be using a web browser to access the site, not your PC's file manager.

Comment: You still seem to not understand how I am pointing out that your ``Alias`` is pointing at ``/var/www/html/devsite.dev/common/``. You are saying that directory doesn't exist, so of course it will not work. That path needs to point where the ``common`` directory actually resides. You then need a ``Directory`` directive for the actual directory granting access to it through Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the mistaken impression that the Alias path was telling the system where the alias should appear but I was obviously wrong so here's the answer for others to see. Still not sure of the trailing slashes but, as it is working with them, I'll leave them in.

```
<VirtualHost devsite.dev:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/devsite.dev
    ServerName devsite.dev
    Alias /common/ /var/www/html/common/
    <Directory "/var/www/html/devsite.dev">
        AllowOverride None
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    Options FollowSymLinks
</VirtualHost>
```